# Error: "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package

I have two react projects, one of them I published to a package and want to import it in the second project. The one that published was written with built with react component and the second one with react functions.
I installed the package and imported it in my component but I get the compiled error below:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/@my-package/src/index.tsx 14:4

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:4)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export const myComponent = () => {
|   return (
>     <Provider data={data}>
|       <App />
|     </Provider>
```

Any idea what should I check/change/update or add? any trying didn't help.